# How to reuse declared shell variable in Jenkins pipeline

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I'm attempting to update ECS task and service by using the following stage in my pipeline:

```
stage('Update ECS Task Definition & Service') {
    steps {
        dir('foo') {
            sh """
                TASK_DEFINITION=\$(aws ecs describe-task-definition --task-definition \"${env.TASK_NAME}\" --region \"${env.AWS_REGION}\")
                NEW_TASK_DEFINITION=\$(echo \${TASK_DEFINITION} | jq '.taskDefinition | del(.taskDefinitionArn) | del(.revision) | del(.status) | del(.requiresAttributes) | del(.compatibilities) | del(.registeredAt) | del(.registeredBy)')
                NEW_REVISION=\$(aws ecs register-task-definition --region \"${env.AWS_REGION}\" --cli-input-json \"${NEW_TASK_DEFINITION}\")
                NEW_REVISION_DATA=\$(echo \${NEW_REVISION} | jq '.taskDefinition.revision')
                echo "New Revision for \${env.TASK_NAME} is: \${NEW_REVISION_DATA}"
            """
        }
    }
}
```

This produces the following error:

```
groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: NEW_TASK_DEFINITION for class: groovy.lang.Binding
```

Am I not escaping correctly? I'm not sure the cleanest way to write this.
Note: `env.TASK_NAME` and `env.AWS_REGION` are environment variables earlier declared in the pipeline.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work. Take a look at the following working pipeline.

```
pipeline {
  agent any
  stages {
    stage('Example') {
      steps {
        script {
           sh """
                VAR1=\$(echo "abcd123")
                VAR2=\$(echo \$VAR1)
                
                echo \$VAR1
                echo \$VAR2
            """
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

If you are not passing any Pipeline variables into the shell block, you can simply use three single quotes(''') instead of """. In that case, you don't have to escape the `$`.

```
pipeline {
  agent any
  stages {
    stage('Example') {
      steps {
        script {
           sh '''
                VAR1=$(echo "abcd123")
                VAR2=$VAR1
                
                echo $VAR1
                echo $VAR2
            '''
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

---

**Update**

You should be escaping the `$` before the `NEW_TASK_DEFINITION` check the following.

```
NEW_REVISION=\$(aws ecs register-task-definition --region \"${env.AWS_REGION}\" --cli-input-json \"\${NEW_TASK_DEFINITION}\")
```

Comment: Thanks so much for your answer. I've edited my question and put in the actual code and error for a clearer description of what issue I'm seeing.

Comment: That seems to have resolved that error. I'm now getting a Bad substitution error, but I don't believe that it's related to this. Thanks for the answer!